# Change a transparent png grey color to white

Tags: html, css

I am working on this project to clone an old [BBC webpage](http://web.archive.org/web/20141031200436/http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk/), I need to use the BBC logo, after searching on google and still couldn't find a match. I decided to inspect the page and check for the source of the image. I found the image to my surprise it's black or some sort of grey and not white as its shown on the page. I don't get how it was done. I know I can just crop it and use it but I'll like to know how it was done.

Comment: It uses image from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20141031200151/http://static.bbci.co.uk/frameworks/barlesque/2.75.0/desktop/3.5/img/blq-sprite_alpha.png) on `#blq-blocks a`

Comment: Should probably moved to http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The image you are referring to is actually hidden (opacity: 0), the image you can see is a part of the sprite as Bogdan commented.